# can't install ionic framework

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

i'm trying to install ionic framework but i keep getting an error when i run "npm install -g ionic".

That's the error:

> npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: colors@'^0.6.2' npm ERR!
>   Valid install targets: npm ERR!
>   ["0.3.0","0.5.0","0.5.1","0.6.0","0.6.0-1","0.6.1","0.6.2"] npm ERR!
>   at installTargetsError
>   (/home/myname/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:685:10)
>   npm ERR!     at
>   /home/myname/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:607:10
>   npm ERR!     at saved
>   (/home/myname/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:138:7)
>   npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15) npm ERR! If you need
>   help, you may report this log at: npm ERR!
>   http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues npm ERR! or email it to: npm
>   ERR!

I already updatet node and cleared the cache.

Any idea?

Comment: It works for me with node v0.10.26. What version of node are you using?

Comment: Try upgrading to v0.10.26 (that should upgrade npm also) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try Like this

`sudo npm install -g cordova ionic`

both Cordova and ionic at same time. makesure add to `sudo`

Answer (score 2):

Have u tried

```
 npm i -g cordova ionic
```

A lot of times its cordovas the problem..

Comment: Also might want to try install again after clearing npm cache: `npm cache clear`.